# Windows not viewing files that are made from linux

Tags: linux, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have vagrant up. Created a centosVM with it. I have shared folders activated so I can share files and folders between my local machine and VM. Problem is that it is one way. My VM and local machine (windows 7) can view the folders and files in the shared folder but if I create a file from the VM, it does not get displayed onto the shared folder in windows and whenever I restart the VM (by `vagrant destroy` or `vagrant reload`) then the files that I created from the VM, gets deleted. This is my vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.4.3"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  if ENV["KONG_PATH"]
    source = ENV["KONG_PATH"]
  else
    source = "./"
  end

  if ENV['KONG_VB_MEM']
    memory = ENV["KONG_VB_MEM"]
  else
    memory = 2048
  end

  if ENV["KONG_VERSION"]
    version = ENV["KONG_VERSION"]
  else
    version = "0.7.0"
  end

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
   vb.name = "vagrant_kongDEBUG"
   vb.memory = memory
  end
config.vm.box = "centos/7"
      config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/tmp", type: "rsync"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8000
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8001, host: 8001
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8443, host: 8443

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "cd /tmp"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "ls -l"
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", :args => version
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html) mechanism for your shared folder and it implies

> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine
>   running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

You can force the refresh of a shared folder :

> The [rsync](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync.html) and [rsync-auto](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html) commands can be used to force a resync and to
>   automatically resync when changes occur in the filesystem. Without
>   running these commands, Vagrant only syncs the folders on `vagrant up`
>   or `vagrant reload`.

so just run a `vagrant rsync` when you need to refresh the content of your shared folder or use the `vagrant rsync-auto`

Comment: would this update dynamically? I realised I once set up a debian system and the shared folder updated on the fly. Whenever I placed an item on the folder on the VM, it appeared straight away on my windows machine. But this wasn't the case on the centOS vm..

Comment: it all depends how you configure your shared folder in your Vagrantfile : `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/tmp", type: "rsync"` means it uses rsync with the caveat explained in the answer, if you remove the rsync type it will be real time